# Fancybox 2 - if no "id" class exists, don't use these fancybox options

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

Having difficulty getting fancybox options to show up only when my lightbox link has an id class in it.  Here's what I have so far (which breaks it, and just goes straight to the image in a new page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisHash = window.location.hash;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers : { 
                title : { type : 'inside' }
            }, // helpers
            beforeShow : function() {  //Where my issue starts
                if(typeof(this.element.attr("id")) !== 'undefined'){ 
                    this.title = (window.location + '#' + this.element.attr("id"));  
            }, // beforeShow
        }); // fancybox
        if (thisHash) {
            $(thisHash).trigger('click');
        }
    }); // ready
</script>
```

Any suggestions?  I thought filtering for "undefined" would do it, since when the id class is missing it normally returns "undefined" when I echo it, but maybe I'm just not using correct syntax for this since this is javascript and I've been dealing with PHP mostly.

Comment: Anyone? I know the fancybox group is pretty sparse, but was hoping someone might be out there trolling it.

Comment: Could you show how your html looks like? Also, could you be more specific about what you mean with `an id class`? (maybe you meant an `id` attribute)

Comment: Otherwise your code works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/ytybcoc9/

Comment: A typical link on my site would look like this:  `<a id="example1" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="example" href="path/to/image.jpg" title="image title">Image</a>`

But in one section, I don't have links generated with an id, so i'd like to omit some details I add to a fancybox window if it doesn't detect an id tag.

Interesting your fiddle works and its the same code, yet mine isn't working for me.

Comment: Most likely you have other js error that is voiding fancybox from working

Comment: I'll have to dig a little deeper and figure it out.  I have a workaround at the moment so this isn't as pressing of an issue.  Thanks for the fiddle though!  Its definitely helpful to have.